# Overflow hidden and icon font in Chrome Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, fonts, icons, overflow

I used icon font (made at flaticon.com) inside circles with overflow hidden.
It works well except in chrome android !

You can see the problem here :

(website url hidden)

(scroll just under the fullscreen slider)

(the first circle has overflow visible and the 2 others have overflow hidden)

Someone has the same problem on his phone ?

Is it a chrome bug ?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed with latest chrome for android update (39.0.2171.59)